# Como obter a tecla pressionada?

Tags: javascript

Estou quebrando a cabeça para criar uma função que devolva o código da tecla pressionada. Encontrei essa:

```
function inicializa(){
    document.addEventListener('keydown', pegaTecla);
}

function pegaTecla(){
  var tecla = event.keyCode;
  alert(tecla);
}
```

Porém com essa função só consigo que código da tecla seja exibido via `alert` e se tento `return` na função `pegaTecla()` não retorna e não é chamada todos as vezes q pressiono alguma tecla.

Como faço para quando eu pressionar uma tecla a função me devolva aquela tecla para posteriormente ela seja testada?

[Aqui está o código na integra](https://jsfiddle.net/leandroMacedo/2tzb9kd5/).
[E aqui o resultado final](https://jsfiddle.net/leandroMacedo/2tzb9kd5/embedded/result/).

Funciona exibindo o código da tecla todas as vezes q pressiono uma tecla.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Faltou só usar `String.fromCharCode()` para obter a tecla pressionada (ao invés do número).

```js
var pressed = document.getElementById('pressed');

function keyPressed(evt){
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var key = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    return String.fromCharCode(key); 
}

document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    var str = keyPressed(evt);
    pressed.innerHTML += str;
};
```

```html
<h2 id='pressed'>Teclas pressionadas: </h2>
```

<sup>Exemplo solicitado nos comentários:</sup>

```js
function keyPressed(evt){
    evt = evt || window.event;
    var key = evt.keyCode || evt.which;
    return String.fromCharCode(key); 
}

document.onkeypress = function(evt) {
    var str = keyPressed(evt);
    
    if(str == 'f')
        alert("Apertou o 'f', chamando uma função...");
};
```

```html
<p>Pressione a tecla F</p>
```

Comment: Ah, agora que vi que precisava do código (e não da letra). De qualquer forma fica aí o exemplo :)

Comment: e como faço para executar uma função assim q pressionado uma tecla ?

pq qro criar uma rotina em q seja exibido uma tecla na tela e o usuário tem q pressiona-la. to com dificuldade da fazer a função executar um comparador assim q o usuário pressionar a tecla –

Comment: @LeandroMacedo adicionei um exemplo.

Comment: muio obrigado consegui fazer o que ta precisando :)

Answer (score 6):

Um dos possíveis motivos é que o uso de `event` direto como você fez é equivalente ao `window.event`, porém este evento não é acessível por todos navegadores. Você deve usar o primeiro parametro da função que é adiciona ao callback do `addEventListener`, assim:

```
`.addEventListener(..., function(event){ ... })`
```

Outro motivo é que você só usou `.keyCode`, para conseguir pegar o código você deve usar também (além do `.keyCode`) o `.which`.

Um exemplo:

```js
var el = document.getElementById("result");

function minhaFuncao(codigo) {
    el.innerHTML += ", " + codigo;
}

document.addEventListener('keydown', function(e) {
    e = e || window.event;
    var code = e.which || e.keyCode;

    minhaFuncao(code);
});
```

```html
<div id="result">Teclas:</div>
```

Comment: legal, não sabia disso obrigado.

Comment: e como faço para executar uma função assim q pressionado uma tecla ?

Comment: pq qro criar uma rotina em q seja exibido uma tecla na tela e o usuário tem q pressiona-la. to com dificuldade da fazer a função executar um comparador assim q o usuário pressionar a tecla

Comment: @LeandroMacedo eu editei a resposta, clique em "Executar trecho do código" e teste por favor, veja como ficou o código, é isto?

Comment: muito obrigado @guilhermenascimento vc tb me ajudou bastante

Comment: @LeandroMacedo É que realmente eu não havia entendido o que você queria, só entendi aonde era o problema, mas que bom que deu certo.

Comment: sim, deu certo.

Comment: mas agora toh com outro problema kkk. qro limpar a tela toda vez q for sortear um letra. aqui tá como está e com o problema :/ https://jsfiddle.net/leandroMacedo/d806crks/

Comment: hahaaha ihull consegui usei o context.clearRect(); Agr tá do jeito q qria

Answer (score -2):

Vi que sua dúvida já foi resolvida mas, custa nada deixar aqui um pequeno *plugin* com apenas o desejado, saber qual código do botão foi apertado

http://dkteclive.com/plugins/keymap.html

```
<script src='jquery.js'></script>
<input class='keydown' placeholder='keymap' autofocus />
<script>
    $('input.keydown').on('keydown', function(e) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $('input.keydown').val(e.keyCode); });
</script>
```

Answer (score -2):

para pegar a letra em si usa-se

```
iputs[x].addEventListener('keypress', function () {
  console.log(event.key) // se eu clicar 'p' vai me retornar 'p' ao contrário do keycode que retorna o código da tecla
});
```